# How to skip headers of a text file when importing it to Python?

Tags: python

I have text file with some texts and numbers. I would like to get rid of the texts and import the numbers in Python. I am new in python so I do not know if there is an easy way to do this. You can see below my text file and what I use for reading the file in Python.

[image: text file]

```
f = open('C:\FE_MODEL\my_file.txt','r')
f = f.readlines()
for line in f:
    f = line.split()
    print(f)
```

Comment: You can just use `for line in f[1:]:`. This will skip first line. Tell me if it work for you!

Comment: remember python index start from 0 so if you want to skip index 0 or 1 then give starting index inside readline

Comment: Can you show us the sample output you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you guys so much  for your comments and help I have solved the problem!

Comment: For future questions, insert data as text instead of posting a picture of the data. Ensure reviewers can Copy+Paste samples so they can help you

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you can skip the first few rows using indexing.

This code does that, skipping the first 8 rows, and then it splits the data out into a list of lists.

```
with open('C:\FE_MODEL\my_file.txt','r') as f:
    f = f.readlines()
    input = f[8:]

data = [r.split()[-2:] for r in input]

print(data)
```

```
[
    ["0.000000E+00", "-0.100000E+03"],
    ["0.333333E+00", "-0.999992E+02"],
    ["0.666665E+00", "-0.999984E+02"],
    ["0.999998E+00", "-0.999976E+02"],
    ["0.133333E+01", "-0.999969E+02"],
    ["0.166666E+01", "-0.999961E+02"],
    ["0.200000E+01", "-0.999953E+02"],
    ["0.233333E+01", "-0.999945E+02"],
    ["0.266666E+01", "-0.999937E+02"],
    ["0.299999E+01", "-0.999930E+02"],
    ["0.333333E+01", "-0.999922E+02"],
    ["0.366666E+01", "-0.999914E+02"],
    ["0.399999E+01", "-0.999906E+02"],
    ["0.433332E+01", "-0.999899E+02"],
    ["0.466666E+01", "-0.999891E+02"],
]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help but I get an error in this line:  data = [r.split()[-2:] for r in input]. It is said : "typeerror: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable. What could be the reason?

Comment: Can you add the exact code that caused that error to the original question?

Comment: Hi, I solved the problem thank you so much for your time I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

As commented upwards, below worked

```py
for line in f[1:]: #Skip first line and continue
    print(line)
```